# Mongoose: Use $or in .populate({match})

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have set up a database like this:

```
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    additionalInfo: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    author: {
        required: true,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
  })

  listSchema.virtual('vocs', {
    ref: 'Voc',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'list'
  })

  var List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);

  module.exports = List;
```

---

```
const vocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foreignLanguage: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    translationGerman: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    translationForeignLanguage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    difficulty: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    list: {
        required: true,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'List'
    }
  })

  var Voc = mongoose.model('Voc', vocSchema);

  module.exports = Voc;
```

Now, what I want to do is the following: I want to select all lists with a specific author, then reach out to the vocs and filter these vocs by translationGerman and translationForeignLanguage: I want to select all vocs over all lists which have a specific value (let's say the word "apple" in either "translationGerman" or "translationForeignLanguage" stored. I tried the following code:

```
router.get('/api/filterAllWords/:wordname', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {

        // const words = await Voc.find({$or:[{translationForeignLanguage: req.params.wordname},{translationGerman: req.params.wordname}]});
        // console.log(words);
        // res.send(words)

        const lists = await List.find({author: req.user._id});
        let allVocs = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
            const singleListVocs = await lists[i].populate(
                {path: "vocs",
                match: {
                    {$or:[{translationForeignLanguage: req.params.wordname},{translationGerman: req.params.wordname}]}
                }}).execPopulate();
            for(let i = 0; i < singleListVocs.vocs.length; i++) {
                allVocs.push(singleListVocs.vocs[i])
            }
        }

        res.send(allVocs)
    }

    catch {
        res.status(404).send({status: 'No vocs found'});
    }
})
```

When I try to test the code, it sends me the error "Unexpected token". Am I using the $or inside populate(match) wrong. When I am trying to repeat this code just "translationForeignLanguage: req.params.wordname" as match-Parameter, everything is fine and works perfectly!

Thanks for your help!

Julia

Answer (score 0):

Just lose the extra curly braces you have in the `match` (around the `$or` statement) and it should work:

```
lists[i]
  .populate({
    path: 'vocs',
    match: {
      $or: [
        { translationForeignLanguage: req.params.wordname },
        { translationGerman: req.params.wordname },
      ],
    },
  })
  .execPopulate();
```